# Codeigniter, password or username incorrect message (database validation)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, validation

Issue 1) I have set up a registration/login area and validated everything (including empty fields) and hit a wall when displaying an error message if the username and/or password are incorrect. At the moment, i can get an error message to display if the fields are left blank but on submit the page redirects to the 'private page' either with correct or incorrect user details. This is my current code:

Issue 1 (RESOLVED):

Controller:

```
//This method will have the credentials validation
    public function credentials_validation() {
        $data['error'] ="Invalid Username or Password";
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_password_check');

          if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
           {
             //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
             $this->index();

             }else{
                 $this->load->model('register_model');

                if($query = $this->register_model->validate()) {
                $this->load->model('news_model');

                $data = array('news' => $this->news_model->getArticle());
                $data['title'] = 'Admin | Home';
                $data['heading'] = 'News Articles';
                $data['main_content'] = 'admin/news';
                $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

                }else {
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
                }    

            }
    }
```

Issue 2) News Article Page only loads 1 article and url displays class name.

News Controller:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/news_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array('news' => $this->news_model->getArticle());
        $data['title'] = 'Admin | News Home';
        $data['heading'] = 'News Articles';
        $this->load->view('admin/news', $data); 
}
```

}

The news model is just pulling the database table, select all and order by id and resulting in the array. Anyone have any ideas why this is only displaying 1 result? I think its something to do with the foreach method?

PS, No error messages displayed from CI or php error log!

Comment: Also, I think that since the answer below solved the original question you should accept this answer and put the new question as a separate question.
For me helping you is a game and I earn points out of it. If my answer solved your problem but if you don't mark it as answered, you are not letting me earn points... and that is not motivating me to play this "game"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way would be to store the error messages in an array e.g.

```
$data['error'] ="Invalid Login";
```

For example in the controller

```
if($query = $this->register_model->check_membership()) {
    $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
    $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

}else {
    $data["error"]="Invalid User Id and Password combination";
    $this->load->view('signup',$data);
}
```

The `check_membership` function should check whether the login id and password combination are ok or not.

And then in the `signup` view page, put something at the top like

```
if (isset($error)){
    echo "<div class='error'>$error</div>";
}
```

Comment: I took your advice and this seems to work using an array (hurray). Now when the user tries to login using incorrect username or password a error message is displayed on the login page, and when correct direct to the admin news page. Another issue has cropped up however and only shows 1 news article (result is in array tried object method) instead of displaying all (no limit set) and the url displays the class name "credentials_validation", any ideas how to resolve this issue? I'll add my code into my original post which now works for you to see using your method- thank you again!

Comment: Try this ($this->db->last_query()); immediately after you call the select method from your model. i.e. 

$data = array('news' => $this->news_model->getArticle());
echo ($this->db->last_query());


This will show you what was the SQL Query
Or enable_profiler to true (Google for it or Check Out CI Documentation), in your controller. This will tell you what is happening with your code behind the scene.
That might give you an idea of why you have only one record.

Comment: @GunjanKarun Explained well